# How to be more DRY in views in django? I need to query and add to context on every view the main-menu?

Tags: django, dry

I have a view that make a query to get the main menu:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
```

and this will be on almost all pages. How do I make this more DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this for use in your templates? if so you may want to have a look at [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be on every page, create [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). And think about caching.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

Though you should check first, if your really need a dynamic menu (query for new categories on each page load). At least you should cache the query.

When it comes to DRY:

1. A dedicated block in your base template `{% block menu %}`. Then you
   can put the html in a separate sub-template (extend the base template)
2. A template tag, that builds your menu (like this:
   http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/347/ *... though this snippet is fairly old, but it should give you the idea*)
3. a full fledged app (like this: https://github.com/rossp/django-menu)